# How can I view disqus comment text in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, dashboard, disqus

I used rails to develop my website, and I've installed disqus and google analytics.

I would like to be able to view the content of comments made via disqus in my google analytics dashboard.  Is this possible?

I've only been able to see how many 'likes' and 'comments' in the dashboard, but not the actual content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to record the comments, you will need to capture them in a [Custom Variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) to send to GA.  However, note that

1. There is a character limit for Custom Variable values (a 128 char
   limit shared between all custom var names and values on a given
   request).
2. Tracking stuff like this isn't really what GA (or other tracking
   tools) is for, and could possibly even violate Google's ToS,
   depending on the contents of the comments

Comment: I realize now that disqus.com will send you email updates if you specify that you want an alert everyt time someone makes a comment.  This is exactly what I wanted.